# Adding random files into root directoy of yocto image?

Tags: linux, yocto, bitbake, recipe

How can we add random files e.g. jpeg, mp3, .py files into some directory e.g. /data/myfiles in yocto?
The step what i have done so far is i have created a  my own layer with bitbake-layers and i am also able to add already available recipes into my layer and then it is added into my image .

I do bitbake core-minimal-image, it get built and then i am able touse the packages which i have added through local.conf or .bbappend file.
i have found this recipe file ..

```
SUMMARY = "Copy mksd.sh script to image deployment area"
SECTION = "devel"
LICENSE = "GPLv2"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = \
"file://${WORKDIR}/mksd.sh;beginline=4;endline=7;md5=d8d50b7d91345eb72f51bbced7fc791b"
SRC_URI = "file://mksd.sh"

#This package doesn't have any files for the rootfs in it, option needed to create an empty 
# package so when the rootfs image is made it finds the mksd_xxx.deb package and doesn't complain
FILES_${PN} = ""
ALLOW_EMPTY_${PN} = "1"


# Copy script to the deploy area with u-boot, uImage, and rootfs
do_deploy () {
   install -d ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}
   install -m 0755 ${WORKDIR}/mksd.sh ${DEPLOY_DIR_IMAGE}
}
addtask deploy after do_install
```

But now i am a bit confused about e.g. i have an .jpeg file and i want it to copy into /data/my files directory into my target system. That means i want to create a directory first named /data/myfiles and then i want to copy an image there all through recipe.
So when i burn my image into my device it should show in my device?
How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just create a simple recipe to do this? That way you could manage dependencies or change whether they are installed or not by just adding/removing the recipe. This is how Yocto should work.

```
DESCRIPTION = "File Installer"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = " \
    file://filea \
    file://fileb \
    file://filec \
    file://filed \
"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}/path
    install ${S}/filea ${D}/path
    install ${S}/fileb ${D}/path
    install ${S}/filec ${D}/path
    install ${S}/filed ${D}/path
}

FILES_${PN} += "/path"
```

Comment: In newer versions of Yocto replace `FILES_${PN}` with `FILES:${PN}` or else you'll get error messages during build.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the best alternative is to create a `meta-your-layer/recipes-core/base-files/base-files_%.bbappend` with your files.

Where you will specify the files and the destination to which they should be installed in your rootfs.

Take [base-files_3.0.14.bb](http://cgit.openembedded.org/openembedded-core/tree/meta/recipes-core/base-files/base-files_3.0.14.bb?h=thud) as an example.

Comment: Why is this better than creating a recipe of your own?

Comment: The `base-files` is already designed to add files and install on your system.

You can create your own recipe, as long as you know how to do it correctly, you can study the tasks and their functions (do_fetch, do_unpack, do_configure, do_compile, do_install, do_deploy, ...)

In your case, see about `do_install`.

I believe that `base-files_%.bbappend` would be more practical to solve your case.